# How do I create a non optimised build using rpmbuild?

Tags: compiler-optimization, rpmbuild

The following command will build an optimised RPM from an SRPM:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild hello-1.0.0.src.rpm
```

What is the correct way to modify the above command to ensure that a non optimised build is produced for debugging purposes?